# TLM-2.0 and SystemC-2.3.3 version

Tags: systemc

I followed the  [Doulos tutorial](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/systemc/tlm-20/) for the development of a simple  bus-based master/slave communication system. My problem is that my code compiles perfectly with version 2.3.2 of SystemC but when I upgraded to version 2.3.3, I got the following error:

```
/home/nabil/systemc/systemc-2.3.3/include/tlm:23:10: fatal error: systemc: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
 #include <systemc>    // main SystemC header
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Is there anyone who had the same problem ?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the code which reproduces this behavior? Also, have you restarted the eclipse IDE after setting the new environment variable?

Comment: Can you check if you are clean building the project in Eclipse? if you are changing the underlying SystemC library.